# Xamarin iOS8+ : How to handle the rotation?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, orientation

I am developing an iPad app in Xamarin and we have to provide orientation support.

In my scenario, I have to add multiple views in a scroll view which I am managing by enabling paging.

Now the issue is with orientation. While the device is rotated I have update the content size of scroll view.

In Xcode I am able to manage the thing using below function:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:    (id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
    {
        // before rotation 
        [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id  _Nonnull context) {
            // during rotation: update our image view's bounds and centre
        } completion:^(id  _Nonnull context) {
           // after rotation
        }];
    }
```

So can anyone guide me how can I use this function in Xamarin too? I want to use the completion block.

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.iOS most of the iOS SDK APIs are bound to similarly named methods in C#.

So for `viewWillTransitionToSize` you would use the following in your view controller:

```
public override void ViewWillTransitionToSize(CoreGraphics.CGSize toSize, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator) 
{
    coordinator.AnimateAlongsideTransition((IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext obj) => {
        // Define any animations you want to perform (equivilent to willRotateToInterfaceOrientation)
    }, (IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext obj) => {
        // Completition executed after transistion finishes (equivilent to didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation)
    });

    base.ViewWillTransitionToSize(toSize, coordinator);
}
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIViewController.ViewWillTransitionToSize/

Comment: I have already checked that but I have to write code in rotation completion block as in Xcode. In xcode they are providing before rotation, rotation in progress and after rotation. I want to use after rotation.